# Java setText not updating after button click

Tags: java, swing

I am making a count up timer using buttons to start and stop.

I need help solving this... when I press the "Start" Button it works (tested using `System.out.print`) but the `setText` doesn't update for me.

However If put the `t.start();` after `frame.setVisible(true);` instead of after `start = 1;` the `setText` does update... but it's without me pressing the "Start" Button. How do I make setText to update after "Start" Button is pressed?

```
public class Cook implements ActionListener{

    private enum Actions {
        Start, Stop, Setting, Exit
      }

    JLabel minsleft;
    int start = 0, counter, stop = 0, close = 0, whileloop = 0;

     JFrame frame = new JFrame("SMART STOVE");
    public void Cook() {

        Cook instance = new Cook();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         JLabel minsleft = new JLabel();
         minsleft.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 17));
         minsleft.setBounds(100,300,250,40);

         try {
            frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\cook.png")))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

            JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
            Start.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 30));
            Start.setActionCommand(Actions.Start.name());
            Start.addActionListener(instance);          
            Start.setBounds(150, 180, 200, 100);
            frame.add(Start);

            JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");
            Stop.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 30));
            Stop.setActionCommand(Actions.Stop.name());
            Stop.addActionListener(instance);           
            Stop.setBounds(360, 180, 200, 100);

            frame.add(Stop);
            countdownLabel.setBounds(360, 250, 200, 100);
            frame.add(countdownLabel);

            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(700, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.Start.name()) {
            start = 1;
            t.start();
          }

        if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.Stop.name()) {
            close = 1;
          }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    final JLabel countdownLabel = new JLabel("Waiting. . . ");    
    public Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int time = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time++;
            countdownLabel.setText(format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60));
            System.out.println(format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60));
            if (close == 1) {
                final Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
                timer.stop();
                System.out.println("Stopped");
            }
        }
    });

    private static String format(int i) {
        String result = String.valueOf(i);
        if (result.length() == 1) {
            result = "0" + result;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.Start.name()` comparing `String` values? If so, use `.equals()`.

Comment: Hmmm.. It still doesn't work.. the setText doesn't update.. I suspect the problem is where I place the "t.start();" ??

Comment: The problem is that you call `countdownLabel.setText()` *outside the `Event Dispatch Thread`*. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->countdownLabel.setText(...))`

Comment: Is `minsleft` what you try to update? It is not used and can be removed from code in question

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I am not familiar with that code, do I replace             "countdownLabel.setText(format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60));" with "SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->countdownLabel.setText((format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60)));" ?? If so It still doesn't work

Comment: Interesting question. Additionally when I added `System.out.println( "EDT: " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() );` in timer's `actionPerformed` it prints: "EDT: true", so it seems like Event Dispatch Thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering how you are running the code, while there is no `main`. So I added one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Cook().Cook();
}
```

Then I was wondering why are you creating new Cook instance in Cook method (very bad naming for Java).

```
Cook instance = new Cook();
```

So I removed it and changed `Start.addActionListener(instance);` to `Start.addActionListener(this);` and it is working now...

I'd also add default close operation otherwise it is not closed really...

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Cook implements ActionListener{

    private enum Actions {
        Start, Stop, Setting, Exit
      }

    JLabel minsleft;
    int start = 0, counter, stop = 0, close = 0, whileloop = 0;

     JFrame frame = new JFrame("SMART STOVE");
    public void Cook() {

//        Cook instance = new Cook();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         JLabel minsleft = new JLabel();
         minsleft.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 17));
         minsleft.setBounds(100,300,250,40);

         try {
            frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\cook.png")))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

            JButton Start = new JButton("Start");
            Start.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 30));
            Start.setActionCommand(Actions.Start.name());
            Start.addActionListener(this);          
            Start.setBounds(150, 180, 200, 100);
            frame.add(Start);

            JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");
            Stop.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 30));
            Stop.setActionCommand(Actions.Stop.name());
            Stop.addActionListener(this);           
            Stop.setBounds(360, 180, 200, 100);

            frame.add(Stop);
            countdownLabel.setBounds(360, 250, 200, 100);
            frame.add(countdownLabel);

            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(700, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.Start.name()) {
            start = 1;
            t.start();
          }

        if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.Stop.name()) {
            close = 1;
          }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    final JLabel countdownLabel = new JLabel("Waiting. . . ");    
    public Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int time = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time++;
            countdownLabel.setText(format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60));
            System.out.println(format(time / 60) + ":" + format(time % 60));
            if (close == 1) {
                final Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
                timer.stop();
                System.out.println("Stopped");
            }
        }
    });

    private static String format(int i) {
        String result = String.valueOf(i);
        if (result.length() == 1) {
            result = "0" + result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cook().Cook();
    }

}
```